# Regex only allow whole and decimal point numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I want an input field that only receives whole and decimal point numbers greater than `2.5`

```
const [foreignPackageWeight, setForeignPackageWeight] = useState('')

<input type="text" value={foreignPackageWeight}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setForeignPackageWeight(e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))
  }}
/>
```

But my regex allows for numbers like
`.1`, `..2`, `3...4`, `5.....`
How do I change my regex to only allow one decimal point?

Comment: `/[^0-9.]|(?<!\..*)\./g` https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: this prevents me from typing in any decimal points

Comment: `/[^0-9.]|(?<=\..*)\./g` Needed a positive lookbehind rather than a negative lookbehind

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, if you answer the question with that RegEx, I would love to give you the +10 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is a form of [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) known as a positive lookbehind. Lookarounds allow you to ensure a pattern exists (or doesn't exist) without that pattern becoming part of the results.

```js
/[^0-9.]|(?<=\..*)\./g
```

Match any of:

- `[^0-9.]` Anything that is not a digit or a period
- `(?<=\..*)\.` A period so long as another period appeared earlier in the sequence